# ThisOutlookSession script doesn't work after upgrade to Exchange

Tags: vba, outlook, office365

I recently updated from Outlook 2010 to Exchange/365.
I have a script in ThisOutlookSession that worked perfectly until the update. It should save the email that gets added to the folder "Ordercomfirmations" in a case folder on a server, but I can't get it to work.

Is there a way to debug code in VBA or am I going to have to guess my way through "trial'n'error".
Or has there been a change in Outlook I haven't noticed yet.

FYI I have no formal coding education.
Here is the script that no longer Works. (Sensitive info removed)

```
Public WithEvents objMails As Outlook.Items

Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Dim myNamespace As NameSpace
    Dim folderIB As Outlook.Folder
    Dim folderOB As Outlook.Folder

    Set myNamespace = GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set folderIB = myNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    Set folderOB = folderIB.Folders("Ordercomfirmations")
    Set objMails = folderOB.Items
End Sub

Private Sub objMails_ItemAdd(ByVal oItem As Object)
    Dim sPath As String
    Dim dtDate As Date
    Dim sName As String
    Dim sYear As String
    Dim sCase As String
    Dim sCoN As String

    sName = oItem.Subject

    'Is the ordercomfirmations nr. over 10000?
    If Mid(sName, 29, 2) = "fr" Then
        'No
        sYear = Mid(sName, 59, 2)
        sCase = Mid(sName, 59, 5)
        sCoN = Mid(sName, 59, 3)
    Else
        'Yes
        sYear = Mid(sName, 60, 2)
        sCase = Mid(sName, 60, 5)
        sCoN = Mid(sName, 60, 3)
    End If

    'I dont remember what "sCoN" stands for, but it's used to check if it's a case or not
    'Probably stands for Case or Not
    If Val(sCoN) > 0 Then
        sName = Replace(sName, ".", " ")
        sName = Replace(sName, "/", " ")
        sName = Replace(sName, "\", " ")
        sName = Replace(sName, ":", " ")
        sName = Replace(sName, "?", " ")
        sName = Replace(sName, Chr(34), "")
        sName = Replace(sName, "<", " ")
        sName = Replace(sName, ">", " ")
        sName = Replace(sName, "|", " ")

        dtDate = oItem.ReceivedTime
        sName = Format(dtDate, "yyyy-dd-mm_", vbUseSystemDayOfWeek, vbUseSystem) & Format(dtDate, "hh.nn.ss", vbUseSystemDayOfWeek, vbUseSystem) & " " & sName & ".msg"

        sPath = "\\server\Cases\20" & sYear & "\" & sCase & "\Email\"

        If Dir(sPath & sName) = "" Then
            oItem.SaveAs sPath & sName, olMsg
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

This is an example of a subject of one of the emails

```
'Ordercomfirmations nr. XXXX from Company / Your order nr. XXXXX
'Ordercomfirmations nr. 6411 from Company / Your order nr. 17731
'1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63
'O r d e r c o m f i  r  m  a  t  i  o  n  s  _  n  r  .  _  6  4  1  1  _  f  r  o  m  _  C  o  m  p  a  n  y  _  /  _  Y  o  u  r  _  o  r  d  e  r  _  n  r  .  _  1  7  7  3  1
'Mid(sName, 29, 2) = "fr" sYear = "17" sCase = "17731" sCoN = "177"
'sPath = "\\server\Cases\2017\17731\Email\"
```

Comment: Just to be sure this is not just coming from a typo, the spelling of your order confirmation folder is really "Ordercomfirmations"?

Comment: Update security settings to allow macros.

Comment: Which line gives you error?

Comment: @cr44sh I changed some names that contained sensitive'ish info, but they are spelled the same

Comment: @niton I have already enabled macros

Comment: @0m3r I don't know where error is, Outlook doesn't give me any error message

Answer (score 0):

So, I got it to Work and I don't know how.
I got the idea to use messageboxes to debug and after adding just one, it just started Working.

So now it just Works, with or without the messagebox, huh.

The only change I made before that was correcting a spelling error, I had spelled a foldername wrong, but it was also spelled wrong in the script, so it shouldn't matter.

Guess I'm a wizard now, lol.